# using sshpass login to remote machine and executing .sh file

Tags: bash, sshpass

I am using this command

> sudo sshpass -p '' ssh @ /home/ubuntu/sample.sh

I am getting  sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
the sample.sh script is not running.

I even tired using the below

`sshpass -p '<password>' sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss <username>@<ip> <<EOF
cd /home/ubuntu
./sample.sh
EOF`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute SSH commands remotely but as sudo user on remote machine, then you have to pass flag `-t`. This will give you a prompt to enter `sudo` password and I believe sshpass can handle only auto login but not `sudo` prompts.

Comment: thanks. Is there anyway to execute commands with sshpass or any other command. Main aim is to ssh using script to server using username and password and execute the commands.